# Cannot update to XCode 6.0.1

Tags: xcode

When I press update or update all buttons in app store on my OS X it shows a loading animation and does nothing. Before this it was asking for more space. I have freed a space and now it is 8.88Gb available. That should be enough right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be enough space. Try downloading Xcode from the Apple Developer Downloads section. You may have more luck there.

Comment: thanks. Is it equivalent to updating with AppStore?

Comment: It seems to be, yes.